# Data are not inserting into sqliteDB iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I have created a table(REPORTDATA) in existing database. I am trying to insert the values in to table. But it is not inserted. I am using the following code.

```
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Album.db"];
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
NSString *insertSQL;
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, & albumDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    int rowCount = [self GetArticlesCount];
    rowCount += 1;
    NSString *tempcount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowCount];
    insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO REPORTDATA (Num, Json) VALUES ('%@','%@')", tempcount, tempcount];
    char *errmsg=nil;
    if(sqlite3_exec(albumDB, [insertSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error Message is =%s",errmsg);
    }
}
sqlite3_close(albumDB);
```

Get number of rows in a table:

```
- (int) GetArticlesCount
{
 int count = 0;
 dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 docsDir = dirPaths[0];
 databasePath = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Album.db"];
 if (sqlite3_open([self.databasePath UTF8String], &albumDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char* sqlStatement = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM REPORTDATA";
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(albumDB, sqlStatement, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK )
    {
        //Loop through all the returned rows (should be just one)
        while( sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
        {
            count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog( @"Failed from sqlite3_prepare_v2. Error is:  %s", sqlite3_errmsg(albumDB) );
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(albumDB);
 }
 return count;
}
```

I am getting

```
Error Message is =(null).
```

Comment: delete the app from simulator or phone & reinstall it.May be table has not been added.

Comment: table is added into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest examining the actual return value of `sqlite3_exec`:

```
int rc;
char *errmsg = NULL;

if ((rc = sqlite3_exec(albumDB, [insertSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errmsg)) == SQLITE_OK) {
    NSLog(@"Insert succeeded");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Insert failed: %s (%ld)", errmsg, (long)rc);
    if (errmsg) sqlite3_free(errmsg);
}
```

You report that it returned `21`, which is `SQLITE_MISUSE`. This is typical if you called the API functions in the wrong order (e.g. performing some SQL after the database was closed).

The `GetArticlesCount` method is reopening a database (which is already open), replacing the `albumDB` variable with a new `sqlite3 *` pointer. Then, `GetArticlesCount` is closing the database, and when you return to the first method, the `albumDB` pointer is now referencing a closed database handle. Thus subsequent SQL calls will generate `SQLITE_MISUSE`.

To avoid this problem, I would advise against having each function that performs SQL from opening and closing the database. Open the database once and then have all subsequent SQLite calls use that one `sqlite3 *` pointer.

Comment: i am getting Insert failed: (null) (21)

Comment: @elavarasan - OK, that's `SQLITE_MISUSE`, suggesting that the order of the calls was not right. Is it possible that `GetArticlesCount` closed the database?

Comment: Yes it closed sqlite3_close(albumDB);

Comment: @elavarasan - That's the problem then. It closed the database and then you proceeded to continue to do more calls against `albumDB`.

Comment: I need keep open the DB is it.

Comment: @elavarasan - Generally it's advisable to open the database once, rather than opening and closing for every SQL statement. The subtle problem here is that `GetArticlesCount` method is opening database again, discarding old `albumDB` value, performing the SQL, and then closing the database. So the code in the first method returns from `GetArticlesCount`, and the `albumDB` pointer has now been replaced with a closed database pointer. You can fix this by changing `GetArticlesCount` to not open and close the database itself, but rather use the existing, already opened `sqlite3 *` pointer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87959/discussion-between-elavarasan-and-rob).

Answer (score 1):

Try to find error by using below code.

```
const char *sql = "INSERT INTO REPORTDATA (Num, Json) VALUES VALUES (?,?)"
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(albumDB, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
  NSLog(@"Prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(albumDB));
}
if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [commentString UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
{
  NSLog(@"Bind 1 failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(albumDB));
}
if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
  NSLog(@"Step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(albumDB));
}
sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Comment: Why does everyone have the same `VALUES VALUES` error?

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, I also recommend you to examine the actual error message.

9 of 10, I believe it is because the database file `Album.db` is not in the documents directory.

Try adding a breakpoint and check the `databasePath` value, open that directory and confirm the file is there.

If the file has **0 bytes** of size, make sure to remove it and add the correct file to your Bundle Resources in:

> Project -> Targets -> *right target* -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources

**EDIT**: In your case, you closed the database in `GetArticlesCount` and tried to use the database pointer after closing it. So I believe [Rob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32219780/3930247) is the right solution.